# Set up WildFly with IntelliJ community

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to set up WildFly server with IntelliJ community version or only in ultimate?

I have found many tutorials explaining how to set up WildFly with IntelliJ ultimate but nothing about community version.

Comment: Why not try it?  Add app server and see if Wildfly/JBOSS is a choice.  I know it is in Ultimate.  Sorry, I'm not a community user.  Just curious - why use JEE?  Feels like a dead standard to me.

Comment: Java applications servers integration officially supported in the Ultimate edition only. See https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=idea&product=idea-ce .

Comment: "The integration with WildFly requires the Ultimate version of IntelliJ Idea." - no joy.

Answer (score 1):

As markswell said, It's doable. In fact, I found it was easier than expected.

Once you have downloaded and unziped your wildfly, to run the wildfly you just need to add your wars files into *\standalone\deployment* on wildfly home (I used exploded wars) and then just run *\bin\standalone.bat* (or .sh if you are on linux distro).

In case you want to debug from your community version, just uncomment on \bin\standalone.conf.bat the line:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"
```

(just by removing the *rem* at the beginnning)

And then, on Intellij you just need to do Run -> Attach to Process... and then select your java process (the one with port 8787).

PD: In case you are changing configs (like adding debug feature) to reload wildfly:

```
bin\jboss-cli.bat --connect
```

And once you are connected to CLI just type:

```
:reload
```

Answer (score 0):

It's no possible natively, but I have created a script to this automation, if you use a linux debian/ubuntu distro you can use that:
https://gist.github.com/markswell/6946a2af38b1fe865d12f50027af8310

You can open the terminal of intelliJ community and to exacute ./intellij_wildfly_integration.sh then to set debug configuration as example on images, after all change to test you run script again.

It's build and deploy the war file into your wildfly

Comment: Script is only 10 lines long, would be beneficial to include in answer so it's more complete.